# Data is not received correctly from TCP socket using C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit edition
I wrote a program to receive an XML file from a TCP client.
The same program is receiving data from another process by a unix domain socket also.
For that I am using the poll() system call.

My problem is, some times I am not getting the XML data correctly or some time it was missing too. But since I am using TCP, if there is a data loss client will know. but client is not showing any error. Could anybody please tell me why this is happening??

I can provide some code:

```
int config_server_tcp(int port)
{   
    int sockfd = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;                     // my address information
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket() failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    // automatically fill with my IP
        memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);              // zero the rest of the struct
        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) 
        {
            perror("bind() failed.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (listen (sockfd, 8) == -1)
            {
                perror("listen() failed.");
            }
        }
    }
    return sockfd;
}

int send_to_tcp_server(unsigned char * message, int size, char * server_ip, int port) 
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    int numbytes = -1;
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket() failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        their_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        their_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(server_ip);
        memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);                // zero the rest of the struct
        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof (their_addr)) == -1)
        {
            perror("connect() failed.");
        }
        else
        {
            if ((numbytes=send(sockfd , message, size, 0)) == -1) 
            {
                printf ("Sending failed.\n");
            }
        }
        close (sockfd);
    }
    return numbytes;
}


void process_tcp (int sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;                  // talker's address information
    int received;
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

    addr_len = sizeof (their_addr);
    int clientfd = accept (sock, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len);
    if (clientfd == -1)
    {
        perror("accept() failed.");
    }       
    else
    {
        do
        {
            received = recv(clientfd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE, 0);
            if (received == -1) 
            {
                perror("recv() failed.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        while (received != 0);
        close (clientfd);
    }
}
```

The process TCP function is called in a loop

Comment: Please show your code, most likely you're treating TCP as a datagram protocol (which is wrong), but we can't really say without code.

Comment: Most likely you forgot to design a protocol for carrying XML over TCP and just wrote code without thinking about issues such as application-level message boundaries.

Comment: are you sure the server is correct? have you verified it with any other tool?

Comment: The bug is almost certainly in the code you replaced with `//do something`.

Comment: I used the netstat tool to check that the protocol used is TCP

Comment: Your code above is missing the code that assembles the message and the code that does something with the entire message. The assembly code you've replaced with `//do something`, and the code that does something with the message has to go after the end of the `while` loop (because the closing of the connection is how you indicate the end of an application-level message). The two most critical parts of the code are missing.

Comment: I wrote "do something" because I don't think it is the reason. even if I give just a printf statement there, the output is sometimes wrong

Comment: @Hari: It probably is. That's the most critical code there. That's where you have to actually implement your "XML over TCP" protocol. The bug is most likely in your "XML over TCP" protocol design or implementation.

Comment: @Hari: I just ran 1000000 test cycles (client->server) using your code and a trivial XML message (`<?xml version="1.0"?><dataroot/>`).  Can you elaborate how rarely "sometimes" is?

Comment: @David Schwartz: "because the closing of the connection is how you indicate the end of an application-level message" - not necessarily, this depends on the app protocol you use...

Comment: I have no application protocol(I just want to print the XML --or any string received from server with may be more than 1000 bytes). But as I said in the question, I am using the poll() system call to read from two types of clients at the same time. Does that causes any problems??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: He posted his code. That's how he does it. `if ((numbytes=send(sockfd , message, size, 0)) == -1) 
            {
                printf ("Sending failed.\n");
            }
        }
        close (sockfd);`

Comment: @Hari: That's your problem. You have application messages but no application protocol. Nothing but an application protocol can provide for application messages. So you're basically expecting it to work by magic.

Comment: What protocol?? My need it to just print the data received. can you explain a little more about application protocol??

Comment: @Hari: You have an application-level protocol message -- it's the thing that the sender sends. Its end is marked by the closing of the connection. In order to receive that application-level protocol message, your receiver must assemble an application-level message and detect its end by the normal closing of the connection. Your sender correctly implements the application-level protocol by marking the end of an application-level message with a normal close of a TCP connection. Your receiver, however, fails to detect the end of the application-level message.

Comment: Maybe this thought experiment will help you: Say one connection has received half of an application-level message and another connection is now starting to receive a message. Where is the half from the first connection stored while you wait for the rest to be sent and received? Where is the number of bytes received so far on the first connection stored? It should be in the data structure associated with the application-level protocol for the first connection -- but you have no such data structure because you never implemented your protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood what you meant by application level protocol. For just printing the received data do we need to implement any application level protocol? Because I am printing what ever I have received. The sender is just reading a file and sending the data line by line. (I know this because I wrote the sender program not somebody else:-))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17932/discussion-between-hari-and-david-schwartz)

Comment: @David Schwartz: yes, that's how he does it. my comment was only a clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is almost certainly in the bit of code you didn't show, the code that assembles an application-level message according to your XML-over-TCP protocol. Here's one way to do it:

```
void process_tcp (int sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    int received, total_received;
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

    addr_len = sizeof (their_addr);
    int clientfd = accept (sock, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len);
    if (clientfd == -1)
    {
        perror("accept() failed.");
    }       
    else
    {
        total_received = 0;
        do
        {
            received = recv(clientfd, buffer + total_received,
                            BUFF_SIZE - total_received, 0);
            if (received == -1) 
            {
                perror("recv() failed.");
                break;
            }
            if (received > 0)
                total_received += received;
        }
        while (received != 0);
        buffer[total_received] = 0;
        // here we can do something with 'buffer'              
        close (clientfd);
    }
}
```

Note that a lot of error checking is missing.

Comment: Thank you David. I will try this code.

Comment: I am sorry, still it is not receiving the correct data.

Comment: Can you describe what it is receiving and in what way that's incorrect?

Comment: OK. For the first two time I sent the XML with an interval of 10 seconds and it is receiving without any error. After that I sent it with approx 1 second interval and it receives some part of data followed by last portion of data and then some of the middle portion. As I said in the question I am receiving from a UNIX domail socket at the same time with the help of poll(). Does that causes anything?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what it is. Your sockets are non-blocking, right? If so, you need a per-socket application message buffer. Otherwise, you have no place to assemble the application message. My code above works fine for blocking sockets. But for non-blocking ones, you need to keep the application-level protocol state somewhere.